# Javascript/Jquery: download multiple images and save locally

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, save

I created in php starting with file_get_content to load a HTML page, parse to DOM and using xpath to find all image tags by class name. Essentially in the end I can resize and save all images locally(because I try on localhost).

The thing is once I hosted my php, all images will be saved on the server. The other solution might be to ask the user to install (e.g xampp) to run it locally (but not a preferable solution).

Could I do the same method with javascript/jquery to save all images found in a page? All I know is javascript can save but has to pop-up dialog save as and that also require to be done one by one for each image.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Sorry its not clear before, is it possible not to use php and rely solely on javascript only? @Andrew Leap, That's a good idea I guess, since I have done it on php part, I should not redo it all in javascript, just send back what php has done, zipping into a one and let client download once. I gotta learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send multiple individual files.  Best bet is to use the zip extension to compress multiple files together and offer that for download.

[Zip Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JavaScript, you can use PHP to force the image download:

```
$file = 'path/to/image.png';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= ".$file."");
readfile($file);
```